# Service Worker Network-Only for a single route

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have an Apache VirtualHost that is configured to act as a reverse proxy in order to switch requests between a React App and a Node Server

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ServerAdmin ###     
        ServerName url.dom
        ServerAlias www.url.dom
    
    
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyPass /img http://0.0.0.0:8081/img/
        ProxyPassReverse /img http://0.0.0.0:8081/img/

        <Location /api/>

        ProxyPass http://0.0.0.0:8081/api/
        ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:8081/api/

        Header unset etag 
        Header add Cache-Control "no-store"
        </Location>

        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:5000/


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/candycandy.filippotiberio.it/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/candycandy.filippotiberio.it/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This works perfectly.

In my react app I have a router that serves all routes included the 404-notFound.

```js
...
              <Route exact path="/notfound">
                <Navbar />
                <Sidebar />
                <div class="E404">
                  <h1>Oops.</h1>
                  <small>404 - Not Found</small>
                  <br />
                  <Link to="/" className="b2h">
                    Go to Home
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </Route>

              <Route>
                <Redirect to="/notfound" />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
...
```

This works perfectly too...

I have also a manifest.json and a service worker that allows me to install the app like a PWA.
This works perfectly again...

Now here is where I have problems:
I need a button that redirects the user to https://url.dom/api/google and that's not difficult...
When I click on the button the request is intercepted by the service worker that sends that to React and not to the apache on the server. The request is processed by React that renders the notFound page.
Disabling the Service Worker the problem does not arise but the PWA in order to work needs to have a service worker installed.

> Request URL: https://candycandy.filippotiberio.it/api/googleoauth/

> Request Method: GET

> Status Code: 200 OK (**from service worker**)

> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Can I tell the service worker to send, only for a specific path, the request directly to the network and not picking it from cache?

I have tried to do something like that:

```js
// Listen for requests
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf("/api/") !== -1) {
    return false;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(() => {
      return fetch(event.request).catch(() => caches.match("offline.html"));
    })
  );
});
```

but it doesn't work.

This is the entire service worker:

```js
const CACHE_NAME = "version-2";
const urlsToCache = ["index.html", "offline.html"];
const self = this;
// Install SWw
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
      console.log("Opened cache");
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});
// Listen for requests
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf("/api/") !== -1) {
    return false;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(() => {
      return fetch(event.request).catch(() => caches.match("offline.html"));
    })
  );
});
// Activate the SW
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  const cacheWhitelist = [];
  cacheWhitelist.push(CACHE_NAME);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) =>
      Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (!cacheWhitelist.includes(cacheName)) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      )
    )
  );
});
```

I know that is not a good question but I can't get out of it.
Thanks a lot!